# Trying to send an email with template

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, error-handling, sendmail

can you help me? I'm trying to send emails through a spreadsheet but with a custom html, I did it in another way and it worked but I wanted to understand why this way is not working, the error in the code is this Exception: The parameters (String, String) do not correspond to the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail.

I expected the email to be sent

[image: 1]

Comment: Why is there a `+` in front of your object in `sendEmail()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify MailApp.sendEmail()

```
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: values[row][1],
    subject: ENTER_SUBJECT,
    body: "",
    from: YOUR_EMAIL,
    name: YOUR_NAME,
    htmlBody: HTML_BODY
  });
```